# Django design patterns - models with ForeignKey references to multiple classes

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working through the design of a Django inventory tracking application, and have hit a snag in the model layout. I have a list of inventoried objects (`Assets`), which can either exist in a `Warehouse` or in a `Shipment`. I want to store different lists of attributes for the two types of locations, e.g.:

- For `Warehouse`s, I want to store the address, manager, etc.
- For `Shipment`s, I want to store the carrier, tracking number, etc.

Since each `Warehouse` and `Shipment` can contain multiple `Asset`s, but each `Asset` can only be in one place at a time, adding a `ForeignKey` relationship to the `Asset` model seems like the way to go. However, since `Warehouse` and `Shipment` objects have different data models, I'm not certain how to best do this.

One obvious (and somewhat ugly) solution is to create a `Location` model which includes all of the `Shipment` and `Warehouse` attributes and an `is_warehouse` Boolean attribute, but this strikes me as a bit of a kludge.  Are there any cleaner approaches to solving this sort of problem (Or are there any non-Django Python libraries which might be better suited to the problem?)

Comment: what about having a generic foreign key on Assets?

Comment: Dave, that's actually exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks - if you want to add that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about having a generic foreign key on Assets?

Answer (score 0):

I think its perfectly reasonable to create a "through" table such as location, which associates an asset, a content (foreign key) and a content_type (warehouse or shipment) . And you could set a unique constraint on the asset_fk so thatt it can only exist in one location at a time